# Comprobar que la contraseña introducida sea la misma que tiene el usuario django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo un formulario de cambi de contraseña en Django y le pido a mi usuario:

Anterior contraseña, nueva contraseña, repetir la nueva contraseña.

¿Cómo compruebo desde la views si **contraseña** es igual a la que tiene el usuario?

Comment: No creo que sea muy difícil, ¿nadie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplemente utilizas la funcion check_password si son iguales devuelve True

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
.... ...
    if check_password(old_password, user.instance.password):
       print("Coinciden")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!